# ¿Cuál es la diferencia entre un tiempo gramatical perfecto y uno imperfecto?

Tags: gramática, tiempos-verbales

Mi pregunta va al por qué de los nombres de los tiempos gramaticales. ¿Qué es lo que determina la perfección de un tiempo gramatical?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las palabras *perfecto* o *imperfecto* en los tiempos verbales indican el [aspecto gramatical](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspecto_gramatical) del verbo, que sirve para indicar matices como el flujo temporal interno de la acción o si esta ha finalizado ya en el tiempo de referencia de la oración. Los tiempos con aspecto perfectivo ponen énfasis en que la acción ha finalizado y está bien delimitada en el tiempo, mientras que los de aspecto imperfectivo ponen énfasis en el transcurso temporal de la acción.

De [Aspecto gramatical](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspecto_gramatical), en la Wikipedia:

> El **aspecto gramatical** o aspecto verbal, en lingüística, es una
>   propiedad que poseen los verbos y las perífrasis verbales, para
>   señalar si la acción que expresan ha concluido o no en el instante de
>   referencia indicado en la oración, es decir, se refiere a los
>   diferentes estados del desarrollo de la acción expresada por el verbo.
>
> [...]
>
> si posee un **aspecto perfecto** o **aspecto perfectivo**, que señala la
>   acción acabada (puntual, finita, completada) en el tiempo de que se
>   trate, como el **aspecto imperfecto** o **aspecto imperfectivo**, que señala
>   una acción inacabada (durativa, en curso de realización) en el tiempo
>   externo de que se trate.

La Wikipedia en inglés [tiene una explicación más detallada](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grammatical_aspect). Traduzco libremente:

> En lingüística, el aspecto gramatical de un verbo es una categoría
>   gramatical que define el flujo temporal (o falta del mismo) de una
>   acción, suceso o estado, desde el punto de vista del hablante. Una
>   distinción básica es en relación a si el hablante considera que la
>   situación está delimitada y es unitaria, sin referencia a ningún flujo
>   de tiempo durante la situación («Yo comí»), o sin referencia a ninguna
>   delimitación temporal pero con referencia a la naturaleza del flujo
>   del tiempo durante la situación («Yo comía», «Yo solía comer», «Yo
>   estaba comiendo»). La visión unitaria, sin flujo temporal interno, se
>   conoce como **aspecto perfectivo**, mientras que la visión no
>   delimitada, con referencia al flujo temporal, se conoce como **aspecto
>   imperfectivo**.

Comment: Excelente explicación, pero creo que quedaría muy bien finalizada con algunos ejemplos.

Comment: Muchas Gracias!